# Accessing GATT services on BLE device

Tags: bluetooth

Here is one I have been struggling with.  I am trying to set up a connection between an rPi 3 and a BLE device.  No matter what I have tried so far I cannot get information on GATT services from the device.

when I run the info command in bluetoothctl the UUID's are the last items that are printed in the console, and trying the list-attributes command returns nothing.

Pairing and connecting are no issue,  but I cant seem to get to the point where the console will provide the DBUS paths I need to interact with the device.

Fresh Rasbian install with Bluez updated to latest (5.48).

Comment: It's not clear what the goal is, this feels a bit broad. It sounds like you've successfully connected to the device using bluetoothctl and you've also been able to see what its services are (or at least their UUIDs). If you want to develop a full app using the Dbus API, then you need to use a "binding" to DBus (not bluetoothctl). For an example of that code, look in the  BlueZ directory on your machine, check out the "test" folder. There are a number of python scripts in there that you can run. Try "test-discovery". Then look at it with an editor to see how it works and base your app off that.

Comment: Not sure what the OP meant but I have a RPi3 which pairs, trusts and connects to a BLE device, I can see the service UUID at the end but when I try to write to it via bluepy python script i get an error saying ffe0 not found, but its there, ive checked and 2x and 3x checked